# Definition of rational number in logical expression format

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

So I have to translate the following definition of rational number into logical expression.

> The real number r is rational if there exist integers p and q with q = 0 such that r = p/q.

I have come up with the following $$r∈ℝ,(∃p∧∃q∧p∈ℤ∧q∈ℤ∧q≠0 \rightarrow r=\frac pq)\rightarrow r∈ℚ$$.  Is this right? If not what adjustments do I need to make?

Comment: I changed my answer a bit

Comment: You should say that for all $r\in \mathbb{R}$,  if  there exist $p$ and $q$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $q\ne 0$ **and** $r=p/q$, then $r\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

(Answer to the original post.) It is not right, even if we add that $p$ and $q$ are integers.  Let $r=\sqrt{2}$ and pick $q=0$, and $p$ say $1$.   Then the first implication is true, so we conclude that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational.

Added: Here is a semi-formal version.
$$(\forall r\in \mathbb{R})[(\exists p)(\exists q)((p\in \mathbb{Z})\land (q\in\mathbb{Z})\land (q\ne 0)\land (r=p/q))\implies r\in \mathbb{Q}].$$.

Comment: It is sufficient that there exist integers $p$ and $q$ such that $r=p/q$ without requiring that $q\ne 0$ since this is an implication of $r=p/q$.

Comment: @ConradTurner: This is not my definition of rational, it is a translation into symbolic language of a sentence OP supplied, and which probably was given in the exercise.